# GRUB booting error

Tags: grubrescue

I am getting this grub rescue error no filesystem thing. I have read a lot of threads on this issue, but those solutions are not working. I tried live CD, and changed the booting option from hard disk to CD ROM, but still I get the same grub rescue error.

I have two operating systems, the other one is Windows 7. I formatted some part of my hard drive during which GRUB might have lost some files. I get that, but now what should I do? Please tell me how to deal with this thing:

```
Error: unknown filesystem.
grub rescue>
```

Comment: If you believe you have done as you mentioned in the above question then you will have to use either CD or USB to recover your OS.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try below link..

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

or can you provide more information regarding your GRUB ... some snapshoot...